# Access media files on connected android phone with python

Tags: python, android, file-transfer

Im trying to access some picture files on my Android phone (samsung a52s) with Python.
I've made a pretty simple program to change the dates of some pictures from Whatsapp which were messed up after switching phones to the corresponding date in the file name (IMG-**20220528**-WA0000.jpg for example). Now I made some tests localy on my pc and it worked fine. After plugging in my phone, I could easily access the media files I actually wanted to change in file explorer but it seems like I can't access those folders in Python. Copying the adress doesnt work. After some research I noticed Android and PC use media file transfer I think and you cant acces files in Python as easily as os.listdir(MyPhone/path/to/file.jpg). Ive looked into python-adb, pure-python adb or pyMTP and python-mtp and a lot of different libraries but I'm getting pretty confused as to what I actually am searching for.
Basically I want to have something where I can go through a folder which is located on my phone with python on my pc and change the dates( right now Im using piexif ). Is there a simple library which does this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for your situation:

1. Install Dokany on your Windows PC
2. Use mtpmount command line tool to mount the Android device on a driver letter

Then your Python script can access files on Android like with other file systems.